# ASP.NET MVC Html.TextBox @class = "MyClass" not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am using the Html.TextBox helper method to generate a textbox against my model but when i pass in an anonymous htmlAttributes class with @class defined like below, the class is never assigned.  Am I doing something wrong?  I have assigned a readonly attribute the same way and it worked.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("LastName", Model.LastName, new { @class = "width-600" })%>
```

Thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE!
I was making changes in the wrong view. This works fine. Make sure you are on the right view folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was making changes in the wrong view.  This works fine.  Make sure you are on the right view folks!